# How to solve NLTK LookupError(resource_not_found) ? It exists in path. (Python)

Tags: python, nltk

I try to use nltk library, but i got stuck.
I downloaded the stopwords library by hand (I cant download by code because of the permission issues on my working machine), but it always gives me the following error;

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource stopwords not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:
....
Searched in:
  - '/home/skahraman/nltk_data'
....
```

My stopwords in nltk_data folder.
So how can i solve this problem?

I tried following;

```
import string
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from collections import Counter
#nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.data.path.append("/home/skahraman/nltk_data")
stop_words=stopwords.words("turkish")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My folder path was ; `/home/skahraman/nltk_data/stopwords`

But it must be ; `/home/skahraman/nltk_data/corpora/stopwords`

I added the corpora folder to my directory.
So it works now.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are not properly assigning a file path to the [`nlkt.data`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.data.html) module. I also noticed a very similar [issue](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2147), try specifying the path using `tempfile.gettempdir` and download it.

```py
import tempfile
import string
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from collections import Counter

download('stopwords', download_dir=tempfile.gettempdir())
nltk.data.path.append(tempfile.gettempdir())
stop_words=stopwords.words("turkish")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i cant download file like this because of the permission issues so i have to do it by hand. So i download into /home/skahraman/nltk_data folder.